# Pandas extract phrases in string that occur in a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, apply

I have a data frame with a column `text` which has strings as shown below

```
text
my name is abc
xyz is a fruit
abc likes per
```

I also have a list of phrases as shown below

```
['abc', 'fruit', 'likes per']
```

I want to add a column `terms` to my data frame which contains those phrases in the list that occur in the `text` string, so result in this case would be

```
text                terms
my name is abc      ['abc']
xyz is a fruit      ['fruit']
abc likes per       ['abc', 'likes per']
```

Can I do this without using regex?

Comment: I was trying to avoid using regex, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope, this works for your solution use apply to check the condition if its present in the list.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "text": ["my name is abc", "xyz is a fruit", "abc likes per"]
})
lst = ['abc', 'fruit', 'likes per']
df['terms'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in lst if i in x])
df
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with regex word boundaries `\b\b`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"text": ["my name is abcd", "xyz is a fruit", "abc likes per"]})

L = ['abc', 'fruit', 'likes per']

pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in L)
df['terms'] = df['text'].str.findall(pat)
```

If word boundaries are not important:

```
df['terms1'] = df['text'].str.findall('|'.join(L))
print (df)
              text             terms            terms1
0  my name is abcd                []             [abc]
1   xyz is a fruit           [fruit]           [fruit]
2    abc likes per  [abc, likes per]  [abc, likes per]
```